# Tests when using Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using the Devise gem for authentication. I would like to know how to test the functionality in my Rails Tests (using Test::Unit) and what tests people normally write after applying the gem?

Devise is applied on my User Model.

Comment: What specifically do you want to test?

Comment: For example, that when a user signs in, they are genuinely signed in and the user is available in the session. The opposite when signed out....Or should I be just relying on the gem working here?

Comment: Presumably the gem is already tested. Won't the rest of your tests rely on logging in anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what kind of authentication you have, you may wish to take different approaches.
In my last app I'm using Devise with omniauth-facebook and hence I did also some high-level tests with capybara to see if app is properly handling all cases (ex. user did not grant extended permissions)

In case you have some simple login/password based authentication it should be sufficient to test if all restricted resources (controllers) are calling `authenticate_user!`. Also in such scenario there's no point in testing Devise itself so you may just check if views are calling proper helpers to render login/out links.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to test devise or really any sort of user interaction you should probably try integration testing with rspec and capybara(or something similar). You can even test confirmation e-mails with the email_spec gem. This book: http://www.manning.com/bigg2/ Rails 4 in Action has three chapters of using/testing devise authentication/authorization, I would check it out if you want details.